# Make shuffle order persistent across loops (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to access the same random shuffling across two different loops on the same ERB page.

**Context:**

I have `questions` which have five `choices` of which one is TRUE for `choices.is_correct`.

My current ERB (below) successfully displays:
1) Grouped by `usage`
2) All available `questions` (shuffled)
3) And all five `choices` (also shuffled)

What I'd like to add is a separate loop (directly after in the same ERB), which gives:
1) Same grouping by `usage`
2) Same order of available `questions` (eg, same shuffle order)
3) The correct answer `choice` (eg, answer "B" = referencing the same shuffling)

Assigning the `question` or `choice` shuffling globally would not work, as I need it to be randomized on each page load.

**Current ERB (currently shuffles each loop separately)**

```
<%= @exam.name %>
<br />
<% alpha_numbers = ("A".."Z").to_a %>
  <% @book_questions_by_usage.each do |usage, question| %>
      <h4><%= usage if usage %></h4>
      <%  question.shuffle.each_with_index do |question, i| %>
        <%= i+1 %>: <%= question.name %>
          <ol type="A">
            <%  question.choices.shuffle.each_with_index do |choice, index| %>
              <% choice.alpha_order = alpha_numbers[index] %>
              <li><%= choice.name %></li>
            <% end %><br />
          </ol>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

  <% @book_questions_by_usage.sort.each do |usage, question| %>
      <h4><%= usage if usage %></h4>
      <%  question.shuffle.each_with_index do |question, i| %>
        <%= i+1 %>: <%= question.name %>
          <ol type="A">
            <%  question.choices.select { |choice| choice.correct }.shuffle.each_with_index do |choice, index| %>
              <% choice.alpha_order = alpha_numbers[index] %>
              Correct Answer: <b><%= choice.alpha_order %>. <%= choice.name %></b>
            <% end %><br />
          </ol>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :assign_questionable
  belongs_to :questionable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :choices, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choices, allow_destroy: true
```

choice.rb

```
class Choice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
```

I've spent hours looking into possible solutions with no success so far. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can give a try to `shuffle` providing a `Random` object with a seed that changes on every page load, but remains constant within the same page. Ref: https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/shuffle

Answer (score 2):

How about you don't shuffle in the view, but in the controller. Save the shuffled array in an instance method and then use it in the view where you need it.